# How to rank MySQL results, based on different values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables in my database by the name of: rank, settings.

Here is how each table looks like with a few records in them:

### Table #rank:

```
id  points userid
--  ----- ------
 1    500      1
 2    300      2    
 3    900      3
 4   1500      4
 5    100      5
 6    700      6
 7    230      7
 8    350      8
 9    850      9
10    150     10
```

### Table #settings:

```
userid    active 
------    ------
     1         0
     2         1
     3         1
     4         1
     5         1
     6         0
     7         1
     8         1
     9         0
    10         1
```

What I basically want to achieve is to select a specific row from #rank by ID, sort it by points and select 3 rows above the specific ID and 3 row below the specific ID but only for rows where the active column (from #settings) for the user equals 1.

For example:
I would like to select from #rank the ID of 8, and it should return me the following:

```
rank points userid
---- ----- ------
   2   150     10   
   3   230      7
   4   300      2
   5   350      8
   6   900      3
   7   1500     4
```

I have created quite an extensive query for this, but the problem is, that it is ranking the columns before it decides that the user is active or not. However I need to rank the columns after it is decided that the user is active or not.

```
SELECT  sub2.sort, sub2.points, sub2.userid
FROM
(
    SELECT  @sort1 := @sort1 + 1 AS sort, puu.points, puu.userid
    FROM    rank as puu,
    (SELECT @sort1 := 0) s
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        settings as p11 
    )
    ON puu.userid = p11.userid,
    WHERE p11.active = 1
    ORDER BY puu.points DESC
) sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT @sort2:=@sort2+1 AS sort, p2.points, p2.userid 
    FROM rank as p2,
    (SELECT @sort2 := 0) s
            LEFT JOIN
    (
            settings as p12
    ) 
    ON p2.userid = p12.userid,
    WHERE p12.active = 1
    ORDER BY points DESC
) sub2
ON sub1.userid = :userid
AND sub2.sort BETWEEN (sub1.sort - 5) AND (sub1.sort + 5)
```

Can you guys find any solution for my problem? If you can provide an SQLfiddle demo, that would be really awesome!

Comment: Which is it, MySQL or SQL server?  Note that it's much easier to solve this in SQL Server, actually.  You really have a regular `(INNER) JOIN` because of the condition in your `WHERE` clause - try moving the condition/changing the join and see what happens.  What should happen in the case that `id = 8` is inactive?  Don't mix implicit syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) with explicit joins; in fact, don't use the implicit syntax at all.  A listing of what you _are_ getting would be nice, but the question/problem description is nice and clear otherwise.

Comment: I'm currently using MySQL. The case when `id = 8` is inactive, cannot happen actually, because it is the logged in user's id. The page automatically checks if the user is active or not before loading the page and redirects accordingly.

Comment: Your query has several syntax errors, fix them.  Doing so should at least generate the numbers correctly, I believe, although your final result set will not have a guaranteed order unless you give _that_ an `ORDER BY` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sort, points, user_id, active FROM (
    SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 AS sort, id, points, r.user_id, s.active,
    IF(user_id = :userid, @userpos := @pos, 0)
  FROM rank r
  JOIN settings s USING(user_id)
  JOIN (SELECT @pos := 0, @userpos := 0) p
  WHERE s.active = 1
  ORDER BY points DESC
) list
WHERE sort BETWEEN @userpos - 3 AND @userpos + 3
```

I made a fiddle here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce034b/10)

Comment: You lack `ORDER BY`s, there's no way this is _guaranteed_ to get the results he needs.

Comment: I have tested your query for about half an hour and it seems to be working fine with my database. Thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is, why [your setup](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce034b/20/0) gives the correct results for `sort`, but [_mine_](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce034b/20/0) **doesn't**.  If it's solely due to the fact that you're using a primary key there (check the execution plans), you're in trouble, as this won't be guaranteed behavior.  @Radical_Activity - technically the `ORDER BY` is executed _after_ the `SELECT` - you know, after the assignment to `sort`...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I guess you are missing the `user_id` setting, aren't you?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it - [the same query is generating a different sort order](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/148ff4/7/0) (I mis-copied the link in the above comment).  If what I suspect is true, this query is _dangerous_ to run, because it could break unexpectedly, without warning.  You shouldn't rely on keys/indices for anything but the (potential) speed you get - assuming a specific retrieval order **will** bite you.

Comment: Why could it break? What is the problem with it? Can you please suggest what changes would be needed to make it "unbreakable"?

Comment: @Radical_Activity - If you look at the fiddle in that link, `sort` is being ordered by something else (it looks like `userId`).  This means that paging can be thrown way off - stuff ordered by `points` doesn't match, so there's going to be strange gaps/inclusions...  [Nesting part of the query seems to fix the problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/148ff4/14).  Remember folks, `ORDER BY` comes (nearly) last, after `SELECT`!

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The only problem with [this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/148ff4/14) is that it returns everything, when I just need to return 3 results above and 3 results below the selected ID.

Comment: How could we add that in your query?

Comment: You can force the order by having a sub query to get the ordered records, and selecting from that sub query joined to the initialisation of the user variables to add the record numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using 2 unioned queries to get the values before the ranking:-

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, points, userid
FROM
(
    SELECT id, points, userid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT rank.id, rank.points, rank.userid
        FROM rank
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT points
            FROM rank
            WHERE id = 8
        ) sub0
        ON rank.points >= sub0.points
        INNER JOIN settings
        ON rank.userid = settings.userid
        WHERE settings.active = 1
        ORDER BY rank.points LIMIT 3
    ) sub1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, points, userid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT rank.id, rank.points, rank.userid
        FROM rank
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT points
            FROM rank
            WHERE id = 8
        ) sub0
        ON rank.points < sub0.points
        INNER JOIN settings
        ON rank.userid = settings.userid
        WHERE settings.active = 1
        ORDER BY rank.points DESC LIMIT 3
    ) sub1
) sub2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) sub3
ORDER BY points
```