# How to add a WHERE statement correctly to a complex MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quite complex query to get some data from the database, sort them and rank them accordingly.

Here is the SQL fiddle for it: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/148ff4/14)

Now what I want to do is, to add a `WHERE` statement to this query, so only limited users will be selected (3 users above and 3 users below, the id = 8).

```
WHERE sort BETWEEN @userpos - 3 AND @userpos + 3
```

So it should look something like this, but with the first example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce034b/10)

I have already tried to implement this WHERE statement to this query, but I couldn't figure it out where should I add, as I've always received error (that the column cannot be found).

Any suggestion and / or solution for my problem? Should I rewrite the whole query for this?

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: The desired result is like the second example of SQL fiddle, however that one is not working guaranteed as it is not relying on the user_id.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a subquery:

```
SET @userid = 8

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 AS sort, points, r.userid, s.active
      FROM rank r JOIN
           settings s
           USING (userid) CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @pos := 0) p
      WHERE s.active = 1
      ORDER BY points DESC
    ) list 
WHERE userid = @userid;
```

Note that this eliminates a layer of subqueries that you have.  Otherwise, it is quite similar to your query.

EDIT:

The above was based more on the SQL Fiddle than on the question.  (Oops.)

To get three rows before and after a given row is possible and just a small tweak, using a trick.  The trick is to define another variable with the user pos and then use that variable in the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 AS sort, points, r.userid, s.active,
             if(userid = @userid, @userpos := @pos, 0)
      FROM rank r JOIN
           settings s
           USING (userid) CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @pos := 0, @userpos := 0) p
      WHERE s.active = 1
      ORDER BY points DESC
    ) list 
WHERE `sort` between @userpos - 3 and @userpos + 3;
```

Note:  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation for variables in the select.  The following is a bit safer in terms of order of execution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT (case when (@pos := @pos + 1) is NULL then NULL
                   when (case when (userid = @userid) then @userpos := @pos else 1 end) is null
                   then NULL
                   else @pos
              end) AS sort, points, r.userid, s.active,
             if(userid = @userid, @userpos := @pos)
      FROM rank r JOIN
           settings s
           USING (userid) CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @pos := 0, @userpos := 0) p
      WHERE s.active = 1
      ORDER BY points DESC
    ) list 
WHERE `sort` between @userpos - 3 and @userpos + 3;
```

The weird `case` statements are to ensure statement executions.  The `is null` is to ensure that the `when` clauses fail, so the assignments are made sequentially.

Comment: This is only getting one row, which is great, however I need to also retrive 3 rows above this and 3 rows below this, as I've mentioned in my first post, something like this (`WHERE sort BETWEEN @userpos - 3 AND @userpos + 3`)

Comment: Gordon, I think he wants 3 users below userid = 8 and 3 user above. Something like  `... WHERE abs(sort-3)<=3;` If 3 (rank of userid 8), cant be assumed, it can be calculated in a select.

Comment: I have reviewed the Query, but it gives me back some weird results. The `sort´ is not ranked and the selected results are not what you should expect using the query: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/148ff4/76). This is the thread where I explain what should be created exactly: [Link to Stackowerflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326927/how-to-rank-mysql-results-based-on-different-values/24328388#24328388)